# Analysing the correlation between two trends

Tags: forecasting, autocorrelation, cross-correlation

I've got 2 growing trends. One is the input (the number of published articles on a website) and I want to understand if the other appears to be correlated (the number of daily visitors).

The problem is that the number of visitors has a weekly seasonality. Which tools can be used for this kind of investigation?

The picture below (based on this [data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dmv_C2_J7uG8zIhxe5aYZbg79MREI8ePsFJTStSKEeE)) show the growth of the traffic and the total number of published articles on that website.

[image]

Comment: Your variable(number of articles) has two issues.  You need to have an observation for every day(like web hits does) and it shouldn't be a cumulative, but rather the amount on a given day.

Comment: @TomReilly: one question: I am looking for a correlation that is not like a spike. It's not something like having my article on some ads for the day X. It's more like now that the article exists the search engines will lead traffic to it from day X on (forever). Can I investigate this kind of correlation?

Comment: Yes, you can. It looks like the last article created a spike.  Is this the case?   You could create a dummy variable for each article that you publish. You might need another variable that measures how many blogs you get linked too. This is complicated.

Comment: @TomReilly: but on an intuitive level I was thinking that I'd like to check if in the periods when I publish few articles the number of visitors grows slowly and vice versa when I publish a lot of articles, the traffic grows more fastly. Is correlation between trends working this way?